# testing using selenium-rc in grails

Tags: java, testing, grails, selenium, selenium-rc

***my project is failing the selenium tests.***

**The seleniumconfig.groovy has the following code:**

```
selenium {

slow = true
singleWindow = true                         
browser = "*iexploreproxy"  
url = null  
defaultTimeout = 60000                   
windowMaximize = false      
screenshot {
    dir = "./target/test-reports/screenshots"   
    onFail = false                              
    }
    server {
    host = "localhost"                          
    port = 4444                             
    }                   
}
```

**The NewTests.groovy file contains the following code:**

```
package gtunes

import grails.plugins.selenium.*
import org.junit.*
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*

@Mixin(SeleniumAware)
class NewTests {

class HomepageTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testHomepageLoads() {
         selenium.openAndWait "http://www.facebook.com/login.php"
     assertTrue selenium.isTextPresent("facebook")
    }
}
```

**the output STS is showing on running the command "test-app is :**

Timed out after 30000ms
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out after 30000ms
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:91)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.SeleniumWrapper.open(SeleniumWrapper.groovy:53)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.meta.AndWaitDynamicMethod.invoke(AndWaitDynamicMethod.groovy:32)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.SeleniumWrapper.methodMissing(SeleniumWrapper.groovy:125)
    at automation.HomeTests.testHomepageLoads(HomeTests.groovy:14)

***My project is failing the tests.*** how to go about rectifying this?

***the command history is*** :getTitle()
setContext(a87ff87c1ae249be99c6363519627de8)
windowMaximize()
setContext(HomeTests: test Homepage Loads)
open(http://www.facebook.com/login.php, true)

Comment: I've never been able to start selenium tests from an IDE, have you tried it from the command line? `grails test-app -functional`

Comment: I have to do it using only spring source suite.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have firefox in your PATH variable? Selenium need to start firefox instance from your installation dir and need to know where you have that dir.

Comment: where can i find PATH variable?

Comment: If you are using windows 7 try [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Your settings look fine to me. Try out this command:
`test-app :selenium`